# OpenGL and GLUT uncomprehension

Tags: opengl, glut

i'm completely don't understanding opengl+glut works.... 
PLEASE explain why he does that? =(

I have simple code

```
void display()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glPushMatrix();
            ChessboardSurrogate.Draw(6,8,50, 0,0); // draw chessboard(6x8) in (0,0,0) edge per cell 50
        glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();     
            //glutSolidCube(100);  //!!!!! 
        glPopMatrix();

        glLoadIdentity();       
        gluLookAt(  0.0, 0.0, -testSet::znear*2,
                0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

        glMultMatrixf(_data->m);   // my transformation matrix

        glutSwapBuffers();
    }
```

And i get the expected result. [screenshot #1](http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/a/0/upload/7688e922.png)

Then I uncomment glutSolidCube(100). In any case, I even do **push/pop** current matrix, and later **override it by identity matrix**.... i think that i would see the same result image with cude... **BUT**! i see [THIS screenshot #2](http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/e/c/upload/e6390ba4.png) What the..... &*^@#$% Why?

If i add code

```
        glRotatef(angleX,1.0,0.0,0.0);
        glRotatef(angleY,0.0,1.0,0.0);
```

before glutSwapBuffers, than I'll see that the chessboard on the spot .....
[screenshot #3](http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/2/5/upload/a642e0c0.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably only half the answer, but why on earth are you setting your matrices AFTER drawing ? What do you expect it to do ?

so :

```
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();       
    gluLookAt(  0.0, 0.0, -testSet::znear*2,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glMultMatrixf(_data->m);   // my transformation matrix
    glPushMatrix();
        ChessboardSurrogate.Draw(6,8,50, 0,0); // draw chessboard(6x8) in (0,0,0) edge per cell 50
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();     
        //glutSolidCube(100);  //!!!!! 
    glPopMatrix();


    glutSwapBuffers();
```

moreover, always make sure you're setting the right matrix :

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt()...
```

Lastly, unless your Draw() method changes the modelview matrix, your Push/PopMatrix is useless and should be avoided (for performance and portability reasons since it's deprecated)